# Connect to I/O remote through VPN router

Tags: networking

I have two I/O remotes hooked up to a router running as an OpenVPN client. I am trying to connect to the devices from remote, but it is not working.

The VPN connection works fine, and I can access the router's web interface from its public IP-address.

However – the I/O remotes get an internal IP-address (192.168.X.XXX) and I can't seem to access these. I am using Pymodbus to connect, but it looks like the router is blocking the connection.

The devices have static IPs, and I have set up port forwarding on the router for ports 3450:3500 to device 1 and ports 3501:3550 for device 2. I have also enabled Port Forwarding in the admin interface for the router.

It still seems the port is locked or something is blocking – is there any additional settings I need to add in order to be able to connect?

The VPN i am using is AWS OpenVPN server, and the router is an ASUS RT-AC51U.

Routing table below, how i would like to access the devices. I cannot access the devices behind the router through the computer, but only the router itself.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

You will need to have a route to 192.168.1.0/24 via 175.100.10.11 on the laptop you are using to try and access the I/O Remote devices.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would this be the correct way to set it up from the laptop (using linux)? `sudo route add -net 192.168.1.0/24 via 175.100.10.11 dev tun0`

Comment: looks vaguely right